# ¿Cómo se muestra el valor del atributo Display?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

```
public class LoginViewModel{
   [Required]
   [Display(Name = "LoginView_LabeL_User", Description = Language_Dictionary.LoginView_LabeL_User)]
   public string User { get; set; }

}
```

A ver si me pueden ayudar tengo una clase modelo que es el nombre del usuario, en Description coloco un metodo que se carga previamente al seleccionar el idioma la clase es `Language_Dictionary.LoginView_Label_User`
que contiene la palabra User o Usuario dependiendo del idioma seleccionado, pero al colocarlo:

```
[Display(Name = "LoginView_LabeL_User", Description = Language_Dictionary.LoginView_LabeL_User)]
```

me da el error de un argumento de atributo debe ser una expresion constante o una expresion typeof, y no se que tipo colocar. Gracias.

Comment: La respuesta que proporcione se relaciona a como hacer uso del atributo Display en la view, esta claro que que los atributos solo pueden tener informacion fija y constante, no puedes usar algo que varie en runtime, definir el Description como lo haces es incorrecto. Si la ides es definir un texto segun el idioma no es por medio del atributo que lo vas a lograr

Comment: La clase `Language_Dictionary`, esta definida como un tipo de Recurso  `.resx`. ? Por que con clases de este tipo si se puede hacer lo que necesitas.

Comment: No, Language_Dictionary es una clase que contiene dos metodos uno que se conecta a la BD donde esta una tabla que contiene todas las palabras por cada lenguaje, y los metodos donde se almacenan estos valores para ser mostrados en Display. Lo que deseo hacer es que el metodo que di como ejemplo LoginViewModel pueda colocar el texto que tome desde  mi clase Language_Dictionary

Comment: Cualquier idea seria buena

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El display se muestra cuando usas un `Html.LabelFor()`

```
@Html.LabelFor(m=> m.User)
```

Tambien podrias evaluar

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m=> m.User)
```

[DisplayNameExtensions.DisplayNameFor Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.displaynameextensions.displaynamefor(v=vs.118).aspx)

[LabelFor versus DisplayameFor](https://forums.asp.net/t/1984875.aspx?LabelFor%20versus%20DisplayameFor)

La diferencia es que el `Html.LabelFor()` renderiza los tag de label en html, mientas que el `Html.DisplayNameFor()` solo escribirá el texto

Comment: me parece q no esta preguntando eso...